# Url rewriting with https

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, asp.net-4.0

I have the below urls

`http://www.mywebsite.com/home`

`https://www.mywebsite.com/secure/reports/`

When user enters the above url we load

`http://www.mywebsite.com/home.aspx`

`https://www.mywebsite.com/secure/reports.aspx`

The problem is, if the user enter like `https://www.mywebsite.com/home`, need to redirect to `http://www.mywebsite.com/home`. Just remove change https to http, since it is not secured

Similarly, If user enters `http://www.mywebsite.com/secure/reports`, we need to redurect to secure `https://www.mywebsite.com/secure/reports`

Answer (score 1):

see [this](http://ww38.netnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet/topic34203.aspx):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
   {
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
+   HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
   }
}
```

Comment: The user is deliberately changing the `https` to `http` and vise versa. I want to prevent that. Will your code work for both case?

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to your Web.Config

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

More references:
Check- http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/